# Best optimitation of fields in a Moon

Tags: ogame, phalanx

I'm playing Ogame. I had some fleet in my planet, but a player destroyed all. It was not to much, but I get a Moon (I got a change of 1% !!).

This Moon has 4933Km of diameter.

Now I have a big question.. What is the best way to use the moon? What I have to build and in wich order?

Have to say that I want to use it to got some phalanx (I'm the only moon near my galaxy)